# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions with react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

firebase permission denied with these rules:
This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete 
all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting 
started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it 
leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client 
requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
your app will lose access to your Firestore database

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore { 
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
        }
      }
   }
```

screen shot of browser console
[image: screen shot of browser console]

[output of the redux state in h3 tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db6AL.png)

code of reducer:

```
import { GET_ALL_SCREAM, LOADING } from "../types";
import { db } from "../../firebase/config";
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: {},
};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_SCREAM:
      db.collection("screams")
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          let screams = [];
          data.forEach((doc) => {
            screams.push({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            });
          });
          return { ...state, loading: false, date: screams };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          return { ...state, loading: false, error: { ...err.response } };
        });
        console.log("error is in somewhere");
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: { "error": "something went wrong" } };
    case LOADING:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: The rules you're showing are always going to reject all access from any client.  Why are you expecting something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Makes the changes in your database rules like the following one.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: allow read, write: if false. I have used this rules for that scheme but then its not working

Comment: Makes the changes in your database rules like the following one.


"dataset_name": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },

Comment: The rules you're showing are for Reatime Database, but the question is asking about Firestore.  They are completely different databases with different rules syntax.

Comment: PrayasAgrawal, I've edited my answer, please give it a try. I misunderstood the question. Thanks to @DougStevenson

Comment: Warning: this will open all permissions for everyone on Firestore and is very likely not what you intend to do in a production application.  For instance, this means _anyone_ can just overwrite all of your documents.  Do not leave it wide open like this; think about your security and more appropriate rules to apply.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you @bsplosion. It was just an example.

Answer (score 4):

The `if false` in your rules mean that **nobody** can read that data, which is why the read from your app gets rejected.

If you want to allow that read, you'll have to model security rules to reflect that. The simplest way is to simply do `if true`, but that means everyone in the world can read and modify all of your data at will. This may be fine during development, but becomes dangerous as you add more users to your app.

The proper solution is to read the Firebase documentation on [securing access to your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and implement rules that reflect exactly what is relevant to your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) `console`
2. Go to `Cloud Firestore`
3. Navigate from the `Data` tab to the `Rules` tab

#### Then edit the rules to be:

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write;
   }
  }
}
```

#### Save

Then try again

**Good Luck**